# How to configure os specific dependencies in a pyproject.toml file [Maturin]

Tags: python, rust, pypi, pyo3

I have a rust and python project that I am building using Maturin(https://github.com/PyO3/maturin). It says that it requires a `pyproject.toml` file for the python dependencies.

I have a dependency of `uvloop`, which is not supported on windows and arm devices. I have added the code that conditionally imports these packages. However, I do not know how to conditionally install these packages. Right now, these packages are getting installed by default on every OS.

Here is the pyproject.toml file.

```
[project]
name = "robyn"
dependencies = [
  "watchdog>=2.1.3,<3",
  "uvloop>=0.16.0,<0.16.1",
  "multiprocess>=0.70.12.2,<0.70.12.3"
]
```

And the github link, jic anyone is interested: https://github.com/sansyrox/robyn/pull/94/files#diff-50c86b7ed8ac2cf95bd48334961bf0530cdc77b5a56f852c5c61b89d735fd711R21

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax for environment markers is specified in [*PEP 508 – Dependency specification for Python Software Packages*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/#environment-markers). I will show below how to exclude `uvloop` as a dependency on Windows platform with a marker for [`platform.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#platform.system) which returns:

- "Linux" on Linux
- "Darwin" on macOS
- "Windows" on Windows

##### Using `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[project]
dependencies = [
    'uvloop ; platform_system != "Windows"',
]
```

#### Using `setup.cfg`:

```
[options]
install_requires =
    uvloop ; platform_system != "Windows"
```

#### Using `setup.py`:

```py
setup(
    install_requires=[
        'uvloop ; platform_system != "Windows"',
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As wim indicated in their comment, https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/ specifies how to write constraints on package requirements.

In addition to restricting the package to a range of versions, you can restrict package installations based on various *markers*, such as `sys_platform` for the OS, separated from your other requirements with a semicolon.

I haven't tested this with pyproject.toml, but the following works in setup.cfg:

```
[options]
install_requires =
    uvloop ; sys_platform != "win32"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to install on windows, specify like this:

```
# assuming you're using poetry
uvloop = {version = "^0.16.0", markers = 'sys_platform != "win32"'}
```

Comment: so if there are 100 packages, i need to add markers to every package separately ? isn't there a way to define it gobally?

Comment: You don't have to worry about it since most Python libraries are OS independent

Comment: The question says they're using maturin, not poetry.

Comment: @kigawas but there are libraries which are os specific ..exception are there always